# is it possible to Declare MultiBindning in Resources and use it in Controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, multibinding

Here is the Code snippet which i want to use in Resource Section

```
 <UserControl.Resources> 
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EnableConference}" 
                  x:Key="EnableifConferenceIsNotNullAndIsStarted">
        <Binding Path="SelectedConference" Mode="OneWay"/>
        <Binding Path="SelectedConference.ConferenceStatus" Mode="OneWay"/>
  </MultiBinding>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and i want to use this in a control like the fallowing

```
<ComboBox><ComboBox.IsEnabled><StaticResource ResourceKey="EnableifConferenceIsNotNullAndIsStarted"></ComboBox.IsEnabled></ComboBox>
```

it is not allowing this and saying as invalid type in the usage

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear:

> A 'MultiBinding' cannot be set on the 'Resources' property of type
>   'MainWindow'. A 'MultiBinding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty
>   of a DependencyObject.

You could however declare the binding in a Style for ComboBoxes:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="MyComboBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EnableConference}">
                <Binding Path="SelectedConference" Mode="OneWay"/>
                <Binding Path="SelectedConference.ConferenceStatus" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use it where applicable:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}"/>
```

---

It is of course not necessarily required to put this into a Style. You could as well directly assign the MultiBinding to the `IsEnabled` property of a ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EnableConference}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedConference" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedConference.ConferenceStatus" Mode="OneWay"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.IsEnabled>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: is it possible in any other way than the style as we may already have some style assigned to those controls